# Need Help on the scrolling Bar in Android?

Tags: android

I have created a simple application
 which has a scroll bar. The scroll
 bar has 5 textviews such as
 Movies, Top10 Movies and so on, also
 the scroll bar has 2 arrow images,
 when I click the arrow image the
 textviews has to be scrolled. Can any
 one help me regarding on this, I am
 struggling on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
san_startimg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        hv.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_LEFT);

            }
            });

            san_endimg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    hv.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);

                }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`HorizontalScrollView#requestChildRectangleOnScreen`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#requestChildRectangleOnScreen%28android.view.View,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20boolean%29) to scroll to the next or previous item?

Comment: can u please tell me how to use this HorizontalScrollView#requestChildRectangleOnScreen function or give some sample application in which this function is used

Comment: Thanks for ur Hint Adamp, Finally i got strikes in this and i post the solution too... Thanks for ur help Adamp, U Rocks........