# Horizontal Scroll view left right arrow display problem?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one horizontal scroll view in that there are images if user scroll and further images are available than I need to display right side right arrow to indicate user to scroll it again and see other images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HI Anand, Refer my answer in my question friend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845625/need-help-on-the-scrolling-bar-in-android

Answer (score 3):

I've just came across this problem and I realized, that you can use scrollview fade function for this purpose. Simply use relative layout in which you have 3 view: leftarrow, rightarrow, horizontalscroll. Set fadingEdgeLength to sufficient length, so when the scrollview fades out, arrow will appear.

**Example:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/arrow_l" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/arrow_r" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />         

    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollbars="none" 
        android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/harokLayout"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is the android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp", below the scrollview, the arrow image appears in the faded area.

Comment: This does not appear to work on 5.+ phones or at least the Nexus 6 I have.